# Rendering a Django radio button

Tags: django-forms

I have this form , with  choices

subject_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Subject_type.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.RadioSelect)

but I want to render these choices with radio buttons in html, but I have troubles.

Comment: What does Subject_type.objects.all() return? Needs to be something like (('1', 'First',), ('2', 'Second',))

Comment: returns the items in a model that I have previously defined. I cannot defined choices manually because they have to be in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can still define your choices even though they are in a database:

```
subject_choices = dict([ (subject.id, subject.name) for subject in Subject_type.objects.all() ])
```

And then

```
subject_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=subject_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Hope that helps.